# Rkhunter verbose cronjob is not working

Tags: debian, rkhunter

I'm on Debian 9.5 and have the following /etc/cronjob.weekly/rkhunter file :

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=`rkhunter --cronjob --report-warnings-only`

if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]
then
    echo $OUTPUT | mail -s "[rkhunter] Warnings found for $(hostname)" root@youremail
fi
```

Of couse, I have changed the mail with my real one.

When I execute sudo /etc/cronjob.weekly/rkhunter to test it, it doesn't work. Could you help me to have this cron work?

**EDIT to clarify:** I have set a cronjob to have Rkhunter send me weekly reports on my mail address. To test it, I can execute directly `sudo /etc/cronjob.weekly/rkhunter` and it will execute the cronjob and send me the mail. However, when I execute the command, it doesn't send me the mail, so I guess something is wrong in the file.

Comment: You are missing `"`s in two places, and `$(` `)` is more readable than ```.

Answer (score 1):

Open an sh shell and type `which rkhunter` and `which echo` and `which mail` to see where your programs actually are.

Then in your script, change the words 'rkhunter' 'echo' and 'mail' to the output of the three commands respectively.